# Thread Join + ScheduledExecutorService not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

In the below code snippet, I notice the following sequence of execution. Why is the control going back to the flow outside the **someMethod()** before completing the activity in the **someTask** block? Shouldn't it complete everything inside thread2 before moving to the next line of code as **thread2.join()** has been invoked?

```
System.out.prinltn("inside someMethod...");
System.out.println("after thread2 .....");
System.out.prinltn("inside someTask......");
```

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new someclassimplementingRunnable());
        thread1.start();
        try {
            thread1.join();
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    someMethod();

                }
            });
            thread2.start();
            thread2.join();
            System.out.println("after thread2 .....");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("outside try-catch");
    }
```

```
public static synchronized void someMethod(){
System.out.prinltn("inside someMethod...");
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable someTask = () -> {
System.out.prinltn("inside someTask......");
};
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(someTask , 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is working as expected. you're just expecting the wrong outcome ;)

Thread2 finishes it's work once the executor starts working, and frankly, its a miracle you get to see "inside someTask" at all, as the executor and it tasks will be garbage collected once "someMethod" finishes working. (i.e. the Executor doesn't stay alive outside of someMethod, and there is no blocking operation at the end of someMethod that waits for the executor to finish).

i would even wager that if you run this code enough times, there will be instances when you won't see the line "inside someTask" because of random OS/process scheduling.

there is no line that makes "someMethod" wait, and so Thread2 finishes its work and it passes .join() and you see the print out "after thread2".

also, remember that the Console is not a synchronic output service. when multiple threads send output to the console, its not guaranteed to appear in the same order. so it is not a good indication of the order of events in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: so is there a way to meet my requirement?  I want the task to be completed before moving onto the next line which here is **System.out.println("after thread2 .....");**

Comment: make your executor static in the main class and don't initialize it from within a thread. the main thread should exit once all the tasks in the executor have finished. but you want a fixed scheduled executor, so when does your application actually finish? it would technically run forever.

Comment: the executor can be started only after t1 is underway and to answer your question there are conditions to be checked inside the **someTask()** to shutdown the executor.

Comment: i think you should use a wait/notify mechanism in the main thread after starting thread2 and notifying only after the threadpool has been shutdown inside someTask. without seeing the entire code i can't help much.

Comment: @ShivayanMukherjee your scheduled task consists of a single print statement. There is nothing inside it that would shut down the executor. But generally, if you want to wait for the completion of a task, use the future returned from its submission method, i.e. `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: I apologise if I am lacking clarity but my question is why is the executor not getting executed right after thread2 starts as its being invoked from there? instead the control is moving back and forth. What can I do to make sure the executor executes its thread ahead of the statements after  **thread2.join()**?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and actually its pretty simple, checking the condition **while(!executor.isTerminated())** does the job. It ensures the next statements are executed only after the executor has done its job.

Comment: this is called a "busy wait" and is generally a bad practice. you are making the thread take up CPU cycles without doing any actual work, and not yielding to other threads for scheduling in the JVM. you should use a wait/notify mechanism instead.